# float parent and child absolute position bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

I'm creating a gallery and have a list of div's floated left, each with a child div thats absolutely positioned relative to the parent div.

(by default the tooltip div is hidden)

ie:

```
<div>
    <div class="tooltip"><p>text</p></div>
    <img src="/images/tmp-gallery.jpg" width="136" height="90" />   
</div>
<div>
    <div class="tooltip"><p>more text</p></div>
    <img src="/images/tmp-gallery.jpg" width="136" height="90" />   
</div>
```

I have a function that can show/hide the toolip div.

This works perfectly in all browsers bar IE6. In IE6 the tooltip div dissappears off the page (I can find it using the debug tool bar sitting top left)

There is one way of fixing the issue, removing float left from the parent div.

Can anybody help me out with this annoying bug? Thanks.

Comment: i can help you with this issue: stop supporting IE6! >.<

Comment: +1 for you still trying to make it look good in IE6, I've given up about year ago.

Comment: have you tried display:none, block, inline instead of visibility. May have a different effect.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
*float:none;
```

in your parent div